# Google Map Points Not Working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I've got a problem with a Google map on a site I've been working on.  The map has loads of points marked on it which are loaded from a database.

You can see the map here - http://www.vineyardchurches.org.uk

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE.

I read some other stuff that suggested that I needed to fire an onload event on the body tag for it to work with IE so I've done that, still no difference.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "so I've done that" .. you've done what? What did you put in the document's `onload` event? Elephants?

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is around lines 41-43 of mapping.js.

You correctly use the form `$(data)` to convert an XML string into a DOM tree; however http://www.vineyardchurches.org.uk/getMappings.php includes the XML preamble `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, which is not part of a DOM Tree and cannot be parsed as such.

In this case you're just unlucky that Firefox and Chrome seem to ignore it.

Either make it so that getMappings.php does not print the XML header (though it would no longer be a valid XML document on its own; perhaps you could make this an option in the querystring), or strip it from the `data` variable before you tree-ise it (which may not be entirely efficient):

`$(data.replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>','')).find("marker").each(...);`

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  Unfortunately neither of those has fixed the problem.  You will be able to see that I have included the second method you suggested and I'm still not getting map points in IE.

Comment: @bradfields: Shame. Seems you have multiple bugs then, as testing this in isolation resolved the issue for me.